# How to store the response of a request in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have the following code

```js
cy.intercept('GET', Cypress.env('activationCode')).as('getActivationCode')

let validationCode;
cy.request('GET', Cypress.env('activationCode'))
  .then( ({ body }) => {
    validationCode = body
    console.log(body);
    // this have the value
  })

cy.wait('@getActivationCode')
console.log(validationCode)
// this is undefined
```

I need to receive a variable from a get request to fill a form but I don't know how to expect it to receive the value so that the execution can continue.
I don't want to code inside the then of the request.

Comment: You cannot intercept a `cy.request()` (refer to the docs), nor do you actually need to - move the alias to the end of the request.

Answer (score 1):

`console.log(validationCode)` This is coming as undefined because of non-cypress commands are run before the cypress commands. So before validationCode  is updated with any value, it is being printed. To avoid this us `cy.log()`. Also the the way cypress recommends to use variables is by using alias.

```js
cy.intercept('GET', Cypress.env('activationCode')).as('getActivationCode')

cy.request('GET', Cypress.env('activationCode')).then(({body}) => {
  cy.wrap(body).as('responseBody') //save response body using alias
  console.log(body)
  // this have the value
})

cy.wait('@getActivationCode')

cy.get('@responseBody').then((responseBody) => {
  cy.log(responseBody) //prints the response body
})
```

If you want to use `console.log` you can do this:

```js
let validationCode
cy.request('GET', Cypress.env('activationCode'))
  .then(({body}) => {
    validationCode = body
    console.log(body)
    // this have the value
  })
  .then(() => {
    cy.wait('@getActivationCode')
    console.log(body)
  })
```

Comment: that is, the rest of the code must be inside a then?

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: is it imposible use the variable validationCode OUTSIDE of the then?

Comment: You can save it as alias as shown above and use it with this.validationCode

Answer (score 1):

[Cypress commands are async](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-Cypress#Commands-Are-Asynchronous), so you should be careful when you mix async and sync code.

You can easily accessa certain property from a request by using the `.its()` command.

```
cy.intercept('GET', Cypress.env('activationCode'))
  .its('response.body.variableIWant') // you'll need drill down to your specific variable you want
  .as('variableIWant')

// some other code

cy.get('@variableIWant')
```

Another way using `.then()`

```
cy.intercept('GET', Cypress.env('activationCode'))
  .its('response')
  .then( resp = >{
     // some code to get variable you want
     return variableIWant //this will become new subject for cy commands
  })
  .as('variableIWant')

// some other code

cy.get('@variableIWant')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, use combination `before()`, `function()` and `.this`

```js
before(function() {    

  cy.request('GET', Cypress.env('activationCode'))
    .then( ({ body }) => {
      return body
    })
    .as('validationCode')   // puts body into this.validationCode
})

it('tests the validationCode', function() {

  console.log(this.validationCode)

})

it('another test of validationCode', function() {

  console.log(this.validationCode)

})
```

---

You should look at [Verifying the request modification](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Verifying-the-request-modification)

> cy.intercept() cannot be debugged using cy.request()! Cypress only intercepts requests made by your front-end application.

Which means the `cy.request()` will not fire the `cy.intercept()`

Comment: console.log(this.validationCode)
this doesnt work